# How to rotate x-axis tick labels in a pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With the following code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'celltype':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 's1':[5,9,1,7], 's2':[12,90,13,87]})
df = df[["celltype","s1","s2"]]
df.set_index(["celltype"],inplace=True)
df.plot(kind='bar',alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel("")
```

I made this plot:

[image]

How can I rotate the x-axis tick labels to 0 degrees?

I tried adding this but did not work:

```
plt.set_xticklabels(df.index,rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Pass param [`rot=0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) to rotate the xticklabels:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'celltype':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 's1':[5,9,1,7], 's2':[12,90,13,87]})
df = df[["celltype","s1","s2"]]
df.set_index(["celltype"],inplace=True)
df.plot(kind='bar',alpha=0.75, rot=0)
plt.xlabel("")
plt.show()
```

yields plot:

[image]

Answer (score 52):

Try this -

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely rotated my labels, however now when I use `plt.show()` now the labels are cut off due to the long date labels.

Comment: @DNguyen : You can probably fix that by doing `plt.tight_layout()` before doing `plt.show()`

Answer (score 13):

You can use set_xticklabels()

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Names'], rotation=90, ha='right')
```

Comment: this Function is not working in my  case

Answer (score 9):

The question is clear but the title is not as precise as it could be. My answer is for those who came looking to change the ***axis* label**, as opposed to the **tick labels,** which is what the accepted answer is about. (The title has now been corrected).

```
for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 5):

The follows might be helpful:

```
# Valid font size are xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, larger, smaller, None

plt.xticks(
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='medium',
)
```

Here is the function `xticks`[[reference]](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2eb0023205c46b24f23a3b767b07b2b14127f272/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L1376) with example and [API](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

```
def xticks(ticks=None, labels=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Get or set the current tick locations and labels of the x-axis.

    Call signatures::

        locs, labels = xticks()            # Get locations and labels
        xticks(ticks, [labels], **kwargs)  # Set locations and labels

    Parameters
    ----------
    ticks : array_like
        A list of positions at which ticks should be placed. You can pass an
        empty list to disable xticks.

    labels : array_like, optional
        A list of explicit labels to place at the given *locs*.

    **kwargs
        :class:`.Text` properties can be used to control the appearance of
        the labels.

    Returns
    -------
    locs
        An array of label locations.
    labels
        A list of `.Text` objects.

    Notes
    -----
    Calling this function with no arguments (e.g. ``xticks()``) is the pyplot
    equivalent of calling `~.Axes.get_xticks` and `~.Axes.get_xticklabels` on
    the current axes.
    Calling this function with arguments is the pyplot equivalent of calling
    `~.Axes.set_xticks` and `~.Axes.set_xticklabels` on the current axes.

    Examples
    --------
    Get the current locations and labels:

        >>> locs, labels = xticks()

    Set label locations:

        >>> xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.2))

    Set text labels:

        >>> xticks(np.arange(5), ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally', 'Sue'))

    Set text labels and properties:

        >>> xticks(np.arange(12), calendar.month_name[1:13], rotation=20)

    Disable xticks:

        >>> xticks([])
    """
```