# Matplotlib unable to rotate xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am new to creating graphs in python.
I have a problem with my x axis "ticks" being displayed vertically:

[image: Graph]

here is my code:

```
Counts = {"Hate":hate, "Non-hate":noHate}
graph = pd.Series(Counts)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6,6)
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = (14)

plt.xticks(rotation=20)

graph.plot.bar(yticks=[hate,noHate],color=['tab:red', 'tab:green'])
```

As you can see, I have tried using `plt.xticks(rotation)` but I was unsuccessful.
I used the number 20 just for testing, I would like to display the labels horizontally. Any ideas?

Note: I also tried `plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')` and also horizontal for the sake of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate x-axis tick labels in Pandas barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244019/how-to-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels-in-pandas-barplot)

Comment: Try plt.xticks(rotation=20) to put after the graph.plot.bar().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graph.plot.bar has a parameter "rot" for this purpose, see:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

Counts = {"Hate":hate, "Non-hate":noHate}
graph = pd.Series(Counts)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6,6)
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = (14)

graph.plot.bar(yticks=[hate,noHate],color=['tab:red', 'tab:green'], rot=20)
```