# How to change the orientation of the matplotlib x ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, pandas-groupby

Following is my matplotlib plot. Is there a way to change the orientation of the x label. Now N looks like Z.

[image]

code is as below:
`df.groupby('Tickets Sold').TotalDays.mean().plot.bar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the argument rot=0. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244161/12934163)

```
df.groupby('Tickets Sold').TotalDays.mean().plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

or use

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

in case that the first approach does not work